# Are there W3C-compatible hacks for IE6 and 7?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

Are there valid hacks in IE6 and 7 for W3C compatibility?

I believe there are W3C incompatibilities when using hacks. For example, using the following CSS code (as suggested under option 2 in this article: http://webdesignerwall.com/tutorials/css-specific-for-internet-explorer?cp=1):

```
.box {
    height:200px;
    _height:200px;
}
```

gave me the following error in the W3C CSS validator:

```
Property _height doesn't exist : 200px 200px
```

If I'm wrong please advise.

Thank you.

Comment: Please make a specific example

Comment: The conditional IE comments trivially conform to the html spec.

Comment: @pekka sorry i didn't provide any examples. when i used this code .box{height:200px;_height:200px;} in the w3c css validator it gave me the following error "Property _height doesn't exist : 200px 200px"

Comment: That's because you've got an underscore in there! You want `.box { width: 200px; height: 200px; }`

Comment: @Nathan: an underscore is an IE hack (not sure which version). That's why it's there and the OP is asking for a way to hack IE CSS and still validate.

Comment: @nathan thanks for your answer,i was just reading this article http://webdesignerwall.com/tutorials/css-specific-for-internet-explorer?cp=1 and could u please have a look at option 2.

Comment: Still wondering why we have to "hack" a piece of software, because it doesn't follow the common standard.... :(

Comment: @daemonfire300: you’ve kind of answered your own question there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This alternative hack should do it:

```
/* Both of the following will be used by IE only. */
* html .box{height:200px;} /* IE6 only */
*+html .box{height:200px;} /* IE7 only */
```

Comment: thanks a lot for your answer mate,have u got any links to tutorials or articles explaining more about this technique?

Comment: @manraj82 This reference is the best I've got: http://centricle.com/ref/css/filters/

Answer (score 3):

Options 1 and 3 in that article — i.e. HTML conditional comments — are the way to go. They don’t trip up the HTML validator, and they’re explicit — they say “use this code for this version of IE”.

You can use them to apply different stylesheets that only fix Internet Explorer bugs. This keeps your IE bug workarounds separate, so that when, for example, [the IE6 countdown](http://ie6countdown.com/) reaches zero, you can remove your IE 6-specific CSS without affecting anything else.